# Flutter - Why do I get 'Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration' from a database query?

Tags: database, flutter, dart, unhandled-exception, concurrentmodification

I'm having some trouble understanding an issue regarding flutters database handling (at least I assume so since that's where the issue seems to be). When I run my app I get the following error message:

```
E/flutter (26185): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance(length:13) of '_GrowableList'.
E/flutter (26185): #0      ListIterator.moveNext (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:336:7)
E/flutter (26185): #1      _MyHomePageState._processBle.<anonymous closure> (package:blescanner/screens/home_view.dart:283:27)
E/flutter (26185): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I've put a lot of effort trying to find why this is. The row 283 referenced is my "for (var element in list){"-row in MyHomePage, but to my knowledge I'm not trying to modify that list anywhere. After some time I just started commenting away line after line to find what the cause of the issue and it turns out that it disappeared when I commented away the "dbHelper.getBlItemLog"-call. That led me into that function (code included further down) where the issue seems to be the database query. I thought that it might be some issue with the database being modified during the query, so I removed all other calls to the database, but the issue remained. How can a database query cause this kind of issue? I just can't understand why? does anyone have any kind of insight or suggestion regarding this?

from MyHomePage (which extends Stateful Widget):

```
  void _processBle() {
    FlutterBluePlus.instance.scanResults.forEach((list) async {
      for (var element in list) {
        String bleName = element.device.name;
        dev.log('Found device: ' + bleName);
        String blItemId = bleName.replaceAll('XXX', '');
        var blItemData = CustomBluetoothItem.fromBle(bleName,
            blItemId,
            element.advertisementData.manufacturerData,
            _geoPos.lat, _geoPos.long
        );
        int tempStatus = blItemData.status;
        try {
          if (blItemData.status > 1) {
            await lock.synchronized(() async {
              dev.log('${DateTime.now()
                  .toIso8601String()} _processBle .. start $bleName');

              //here's where I call the troubling function

              await dbHelper.getBlItemLog(
                  bleName: bleName, startDate: blItemData.sDate)
                  .then((queueItem) async {
                // the stuff in here is commented away for now and thus doesn't matter
              });


              dev.log('${DateTime.now()
                  .toIso8601String()} _processBle .. stop ${element.device
                  .name}');
            });
          }
        } catch (e) {
          dev.log('error : $e');
        }
      }
    });
    firstStartup = false;
    dev.log('_processBle - ### done');
  }
```

from my dbHelper:

```
  Future<CustomBluetoothItem?> getBlItemLog({required String bleName, required String startDate}) async {
    Database? db = await database;

   //the following line seems to be where the issue is, since there's no issue if I comment it away.
    
   List<Map<String, dynamic>> maps = await db!.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM ble_table WHERE bleName = ? AND startDate = ? ORDER BY createDate desc limit 1 offset 0',[bleName,startDate]);
    
    if (maps.isNotEmpty) {
      return CustomBluetoothItem.fromJson(maps[0]);
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're doing wrong when you've posted so much code and don't have an example that would let other people easily reproduce your problem.  In general, if you're doing a lot of work in a loop that could potentially modify the collection you're iterating over, you probably should iterate over a copy of that collection instead.

Comment: @jamesdlin Yeah, I'm having a hard time reproducing the problem myself since I don't know whats causing it... Most of the code I posted was to get the "lay of the land" so to speak, but I tried to mark the rows where the issue seemed to be with comments, but maybe I wasn't clear enough? Also, I tried making a copy of that collection, but it didn't seem to make any difference. But maybe I did so in an incorrect way? Flutter is still a bit new to me... Do you have any suggestion for how to do so?

Comment: Try iterating over `FlutterBluePlus.instance.scanResults.toList()` for the outer loop and then iterating over `list.toList()` for the inner loops.